# IIS7: Have host header route to specific down folder and page

Tags: redirect, iis-7, hostheaders, hostheader

I have two host headers for a single webpage:

1. www.a.com
2. www.b.com

both currently point to the index.html page. I want www.b.com to go to a specific directory and page:

www.b.com/otherfolder/index.html

Is this possible through the IIS UI or do I have to hard code this in the web config file? If hard coding is required, how would I write this?